# Clearcase Trigger Cant open perl script - invalid argument

Tags: perl, triggers, clearcase

Our triggers are failing with an invalid argument.

The `mktrtype` command applies the trigger successfully but the trigger fail when called.
Triggers are stored on Aix server and we on windows clients.
Samba is set up and I can see and update the triggers from windows.

command example:

```
mktrtype -nc -ele -all -rep -pre lnname -nusers beanged -execwin \"ccperl \\\\vob server\\triggers\\evil.pl\" -execunix \"perl /triggers/evil.pl\" PREOP_LNNAME
```

To check that the `mktrype` command has run successfully, I have added or removed userid's from the `-nusers` and I can see the changes when checking the trigger via the GUI.
If I exclude my if from a trigger it then fails on next trigger as all created in same way.

Full error:

```
Error Adding <viewname>text.txt to source control  
Can't open perl script  
"\\vob server\triggers\preop_chkpathlen.pl" : invalid argument  
Trigger "PREOP_CHKPATHLEN" has refused to let checkout proceed.
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: There seems to be a `\"` missing after he first `evil.pl`

Comment: Sorry my fault with a typo as hadnt been able to copy and paste in. Also from what i entered original the execwin part has doubled up \ but these have been removed in the actual post. eg \\\\vob server\\triggers

Comment: Is it possible to fdouble the double backslashes? `\\\\\\\\ ` The goal is to use `\\vob server`, not `\vob server`

Comment: When checking the trigger in the Explore Types of the GUI I can see it showing as  ccperl \\vob server\triggers\evil.pl

Comment: Since this is likely the same environment causing the other problems, have you verified that you can open the trigger script in a text editor, or even get to. \\server\triggers in windows explorer?

Comment: Hi, from the windows client i have a drive mapped pointing to \\server\triggers and can view and update the trigger scripts which are in perl.  The triggers folder was protected by the CC Admin group as opposed to CC Users so updated that and the protections of the folder content. I've run the script creation as root.  as my own userid I can now update Clearcase but a colleague is not able to. I'm checking her user set up and also that of another colleage as comparison.

Comment: with my id in win exp i can enter \\server\triggers but colleagues are not able to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the prompts to the solution.
The other users were not defined to samba (as had been told they were) and once done and passwords sync'd all is ok and no longer getting trigger invalid argument error.